# VGA impedance matching

Tags: connector, impedance-matching, vga

i have VGA in one side of my circuit and I want to connect that to a connector with 50 ohm impedance. after that I must convert 50 ohm impedance to 75 ohm, because I have a vga cable in other side. in other word I have two VGA cable that there is one connector between them with 50 ohm impedace.how I can Do this?
VGA(1080*1920)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the length of a 50 Ohm connector is << 10% of wavelength at say roughly 100MHz bandwidth of  2 million pixels refreshed at 60Hz Vertical sync rate, **so no conversion or adapter** is needed.

50 Ohm BNC connectors *I believe* were  used on old NEC CRT RGB monitors without issues but used 3x 75 Ohm cable and possibly other cable for separated sync.

... as Brian points out they must have been 75 Ohm BNC. This is due to ratio of diameter of  ground and inner pin being higher which is what determines √(L/C) ratio and thus Z.

... Later, Dan points out that  BNC's 50/75 Ohm have the same pin size.  So I checked it out and they are indeed the same, so my memory was ok. (ha)

[image]

(this is not an endorsement for cheap err. inexpensive Pasternack connectors, that often do not have return loss specs at their rated GHz but for BNC it is fine.) GHz RF connectors are micromachined critical parts. Don't go cheap unless it doesn't matter.)

### Suggestion

Get 75 Ohm connectors for better coax fit if that matters.
https://www.pasternack.com/75-ohm-bnc-connectors-category.aspx

Comment: But beware of mixing 50 and 75 ohm BNC connectors ... the central pins have a subtly different diameter so one plug can destroy the other socket (and I can never remember which way round was taboo).

Comment: Aha thanks Brian, since Z is related to ratio of OD/ID the 75 ohm BNC should have a smaller pin so the 50 Ohm BNC pin will swuage open the socket.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This is true for N type connectors but not for BNCs where the impedance is controlled by extending the dielectric in one variant and using air in the other, 50 and 75 ohm BNC inter mate just fine with no damage.

Comment: As I found out,no conversion is needed for VGA signals(for my challenge). But why you wrote about BNC connector? I don't understand why BNC is important for my work?is it important?

Comment: It was just an example of a 50R connector since you failed to mention what you are using

Answer (score 0):

If the op is referring to bnc connectors they have a wide bandwith to begin with at low impedance (1K ohm or less). This is why they are extensively used in test equipment (other than there quick release operation). From time to time I install a special atomic clock used in professional recording studios. They run at 10mhz @ 75 ohms. I use Rg59 bnc cables there.

But mechanically, the standard 50ohm bnc is different from the a/v 75 ohm bnc. So either revise the 50 ohm bnc connectors or change your cable ends to match technology. Either way it will work you just have to be consistent with the connector technology.